# Нужно ли читать книги по программированию

Tags: веб-программирование, функциональное-программирование

Я учусь сейчас в ВУЗЕ и не как не могу решить читать ли мне книги по программированию или нет подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: А сейчас вы что делаете? Просто ходите на пары? Читаете какие-то гайды? Из гайдов ещё можно по частям насобирать нужную информацию, но с пар - вряд ли.

Comment: Упомянуто функциональное программирование - прочтите SICP. Веб -  Douglas Crockford, JavaScript: The Good Parts (есть перевод). ClojureScript объединяет обе темы и ещё добавляет persistent data structure: https://clojure.org/community/books.

Comment: Прямо "от корки до корки" можно не читать, можно читать выборочно, либо вообще использовать только как справочный материал.

Answer (score 4):

Если вы желаете научиться программированию - то читать книги нужно. Это единственный способ научиться, в ВУЗе вас программировать не научат.

Comment: То что читать нужно согласен, но не согласен с тем что это единственный способ. Много хороших сайтов есть по которым можно учить. Еще некоторые ютуберы хорошо объясняют. Конечно начальный гвоздь ютубом не забить, но это тоже способ научиться. Говорю как человек, который никогда не открыл книги по программировнию.

Comment: @eccs0103 хорошие сайты, по которым можно учить - это, по сути, те же книги, только электронные. А ютуба лучше бы тоже избегать, там слишком много мусора и нет возможности отличить нормальный ролик от мусорного.